# Excel VBA: Using variable in place of item in quotation marks

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the contents of a cell in a different workbook, but would like the user to be able to specify which cell to start in by typing the name of the cell into a cell in the current workbook (that the macro code is in).

(By the way, please excuse the elementary nature of this question as well as any obvious mistakes I am making vocabulary-wise; I am new at trying my hand at this!)

I have come up with the following code, but am getting a "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" message.

(Please note that I have also used user input to refer to the different workbook. That part worked.)

```
Sub OpenWorkBook()

    Dim Src As Workbook
    Set Src = Workbooks.Open(Range("B3"))

    Dim StrtCell As String
    StrtCell = Range("B4")

    Src.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(StrtCell).Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Range("A6").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Once you've opened the `Src` workbook, the active sheet will be a sheet in that workbook (which ever one was active when t was last saved).  So, your `StrtCell` will read from B4 on that sheet, not the same sheet as you read B3 from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to always qualify your `Range()` calls with an explicit worksheet object, otherwise they will use whatever happens to be the Activesheet at the time.

Relying on some specific sheet being active when a particular line runs makes your code brittle and difficult to debug.

```
Sub OpenWorkBook()

    Dim Src As Workbook
    Dim StrtCell As String
    Dim sht as Worksheet

    Set sht = Activesheet

    Set Src = Workbooks.Open(sht.Range("B3"))
    StrtCell = sht.Range("B4")

    Src.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(StrtCell).Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    sht.Range("A6").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks so much for your very quick reply! I look forward to trying it out soon, and will keep you posted.

Comment: Hi again, Tim, It worked perfectly! Thanks so much for the answer -- and for helping me improve my understanding! Best regards.